# SQL Server function inside a Select statement and transaction deadlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, stored-functions, database-deadlocks

With the code shown below I am getting a transaction deadlock. The `Split` function takes a string and splits the list into a table which I do a select on. I event have `READ UNCOMMITTED`. Should I put the `Split` into a temp table and then do a query with it?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Revisions]
    @ScheduleRevisionIds NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

    IF(@ScheduleRevisionIds IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        -- GET SCHEDULE REVISIONS
        SELECT esr.Id 
        INTO #TempScheduleRevisions
        FROM Revision esr
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT items 
                      FROM dbo.Split(@ScheduleRevisionIds, ',') 
                      WHERE esr.Id = items)
```

**Function**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [Split](@String varchar(MAX), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(MAX))       
as       
begin       
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(MAX)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        SET @String = right(@String, LEN(@String) - @idx)       
        IF LEN(@String) = 0 BREAK       
    END   
RETURN       
END
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the `split()` function?

Comment: Assuming you have a reasonably written split function, I don't see how a deadlock can occur within the little bit of code posted. You will need to dig deeper into the code executed by the connections competing for resource access. At the very least you need to identify the resource(s) in contention.

Comment: `(1)` Which version of SQL Server you use? From 2016 you can use the build-in function STRING_SPLIT. `(2)` Why do you need this split function? You split a string by "," in order to scan the result and check if specific text exists... why not simply check if the text exists in the original string? Add "," at the beginning of the string and check if (","+esr.Id+",") exists in the string (","+@ScheduleRevisionIds+",") using something like `where CHARINDEX(","+esr.Id+",", ","+@ScheduleRevisionIds+",") > 0`

Comment: If you can post the table DD+DML+ expected result then we will probably be able to provide a full solution/demo fast

Comment: There is not enough information here to tell, as there must be something else causing a deadlock. One thing I have found is the Select INTO can cause locking, where a CREATE TABLE followed by an INSERT does not. You can try that.

Comment: You should add the rest of the procedure to the question. The part that you have there now is inefficient, but should, as far as I can tell, not by itself cause deadlocks unless (possibly..?) you are using `MARS` on the connection.

Comment: I put the Function for the split.  The reason why I compared on the split parts is because I want to test against an index key, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have anything concrete to say any part of your query would lead to transaction deadlock. But, I think you can use JOINs which I feel is simpler and might get you out of troublesome deadlocks. So, Try this:

```
 SELECT esr.Id INTO #TempScheduleRevisions
 FROM 
 Revision esr
 INNER JOIN
 dbo.Split(@ScheduleRevisionIds, ',') sri
 ON
 sri.items = esr.id
```